# Input Validation for PHP form

Tags: php, html

I wonder why is the gender option reseting to blank if I click the create button with invalid input. It must be the same value to the one I selected before and after the validation. See my codes here: 
http://pastebin.com/gKLEWS3h

for now the First Name and the Gender are the ones working. Thank you for helping im still learning.

Comment: why is everybody down voting? am I dumb enough to not notice something?

Comment: Please downvote by giving explanation. It is just depressing for new user to ask question.

Comment: it is so depressing that they are down voting without telling me why. :(

Comment: Two reasons I see: 1) Paste code here, not on an external service where it can be lost/removed. 2) Your question doesn't show a lot of effort: what have you tried ? What are the values of the variables when you have the error ? (vardump much?) etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While marius' answer is right; the fact that variables are **case-sensitive**, so you'll either have to use `$Gender` all over, or `$gender` all over - you can choose yourself, but stick to one. In PHP-standards, typically variable-names start with lowercase letters, but it works either way (as long as you always keep the same name for the same variable).

You also have some redundancy in your code (like `else`-statements that do nothing). I'd suggest something like this. Makes for easier reading, and as long as you use the proper names for your variables, it works too.

```
<select class="form-control" id="inputGender" name="Gender" >
    <option></option>
    <option value="male" <?php if ($Gender == 'male') echo 'selected'; ?>>Male</option>
    <option value="female" <?php if ($Gender == 'female') echo 'selected'; ?>>Female</option>
</select>
```

Comment: so its the casing thank you very much for pointing it out didn't notice it at all Awesome. finally im unstucked.

Answer (score 0):

you should try this one

```
 if (isset($gender) && $gender=='male'){
      echo "select='selected'";
     } else{
           echo '';
     }
} else{
         echo '';
  }
?>>Male</option>
<option value="female" <?php
 if (isset($gender) && $gender=='female'){
    echo "select='selected'";
             }else{
               echo '';
                 }
     }   else{
        echo '';
        }
```

try it .. write it in proper sequence if you wish. thanx

Comment: i think this is the optimized version of my gender validation. Still the same results. I removed the inside else i think that is not needed. Thank you for cleaning my code anyways!

Answer (score 0):

case sensitive  $Gender, change to $gender all over.

you get the data with this variable $Gender, and try to call like $gender ?!?

Comment: thank you very much for pointing it out sir im sorry didnt notice it at all. i got confused. awesome thank you :).